# Как задать градиент для Android?

Tags: android, css

Как задать в CSS градиент для Android? Это все не работает(

```
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.3)  50%,   rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.55)  50%);
     background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.3)  50%,   rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.55)  50%);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.3)  50%,   rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.55)  50%);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.3)  50%,   rgba(177, 184, 200, 0.55)  50%);
```

Comment: может просто не видно css??

Comment: видно проблема тока с градиентом

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что эти свойства цсски - просто не поддерживаются браузером дрончика.. =) Поищи просто другой способ...

Answer (score 1):

у меня это градиент

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FF000000"
            android:centerColor="#FF000000"
            android:endColor="#FF777777"
            android:angle="90" />
    </shape>
```

тут его применение

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    ....
```

Comment: я использую HTML

Comment: @Gorets Ваш градиент относится к View элементам и тому подобному, автор изначально писал про CSS